# Another way to say "almost kills"

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I am searching for a one-word solution to replace "almost kills" in the sentence:

"When a devoted mother confronts a health care system that almost kills her daughter, her alter ego, desperate to protect…"

Comment: "Almost kills" is probably the best generic term.  Anything else would have to be longer and likely distracting in the above.  Eg, "within an inch of her life" is too "cute" -- you want something dry and fairly clinical in the above.

Comment: *Wounds* is the general term for inflicting injury short of death, but does not convey the level of grievousness,

Comment: Are you really talking about an actual event in the past? “... system that almost ***killed*** her daughter...”?

Comment: Why is her alter ego doing anything?  What's wrong with her ego?

Comment: @Jim It is for a finished script in which I played a bit with the future when I wrote it. In it, (if he had been, which he was) the new President Trump would replace Obamacare (which he did – almost) with something so much better that now 25 million Americans face a possible death trap if they do not come up with the money for their treatment.

Comment: @Xanne – Her first son came from the war as a broken man, committed suicide. Her second son came from the war without a leg and is on the best way to follow his older brother. Now her only daughter goes to war to financially help her family and returns wounded and … the rest you can find in my answer to Jim.

Comment: So maybe you’re using the historical present tense with “*almost kills*”?

Comment: @Jim Exactly. First, the military excludes her daughter from their top-notch health care system that they have. Once in a public hospital, her mother confronts the consequences of the man who promised to make America great again (and fill his pockets doing so). That is when she snaps. She decides to end the suffering of all those patients (including prisoners with psychological problems, which were moved to public hospitals). That is when her mother turns into a soon to be a mass murderer. At the end things clear up for her and her family.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your options include: imperils, jeopardises, endangers

(http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/endanger)